# Training of map/reduce functional programming

Tags: python, math, lambda, reduce, factorial

I want to calculate in Python the log factorial of all numbers contained in a list but as a result I only get a 'ValueError: math domain error' - where does this come from?

```
from _functools import reduce
import math

nums_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
nums_log_fac = reduce (lambda x, y : (math.log10(x)) + (math.log10(y)), nums_list)
print (nums_log_fac)
```

Comment: What language is this? [Edit] to tag it, please.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that at one point `math.log10()` is being called with a negative value which triggers the domain error.  Remember, the first pass of `reduce` uses the first two values of your iterable for `x` and `y` (assuming no initializer).  But, on each subsequent pass `x` represents the value returned by the previous `lambda` call and `y` is the next value in the iterable.

Example:

```
from functools import reduce
import math

def do_log10(x, y):
    print(f"x:{x:>5.2f}, y:{y:>5.2f}")
    return math.log10(x) + math.log10(y)

nums_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
nums_log_fac = reduce(do_log10, nums_list)
print (nums_log_fac)
```

Output:

```
x: 1.00, y: 2.00
x: 0.30, y: 3.00
x:-0.04, y: 4.00
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-2bec9dea93b2> in <module>
      7 
      8 nums_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
----> 9 nums_log_fac = reduce(do_log10, nums_list)
     10 print (nums_log_fac)

<ipython-input-25-2bec9dea93b2> in do_log10(x, y)
      4 def do_log10(x, y):
      5     print(f"x:{x:>5.2f}, y:{y:>5.2f}")
----> 6     return math.log10(x) + math.log10(y)
      7 
      8 nums_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

ValueError: math domain error
```